# Will provisioning a second time re-run all the shell commands in my script?

Tags: shell, vagrant, provisioning

I'm developing a Vagrant shell script to set up an Ubuntu VM with a whole bunch of things installed. I'm noticing that running `sudo apt-get update` during provisioning is taking a long time, and so testing that my Vagrant scripts are setting up the VM correctly is really slow.

If I run `vagrant provision` a second time, is it going to re-run all the shell commands in my script, or will it only re-run newly added setup stuff? I really want to reduce the development time for this script!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Bypass Logic in Your Provisioning Script

When you re-run a given Vagrant shell provisioner, it must re-run the whole script. Any bypasses or short-circuiting you might want to apply must be designed into your script as conditional statements. As one example:

```
# Only install something if a certain file is missing.
if [ ! -f /some/file ]; then
    : # run your installer
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will re-run all the shell commands in your script. You can write a script which checks for the existence of a file. If file exists run the script and create the file so that next time file will be there and script won't execute.